# How do I render a view on a side menu in ionic 1?

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework

I have created a side-menu but I can't get the views I want on it. How do I solve this problem? My routing works fine as it shows that the app is in the /app/book url but the Controller is not invoked and no view is being rendered. I do not know what the problem is, thanks in advance. Below is my code:

app.js

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
$stateProvider
.state('app', {
url: '/app',
abstract: true,
tenplateUrl: 'templates/side-menu.html',
controller: 'app-CTRL'
})

.state('app.book', {
url: '/book',
views: {
  'menuContent': {
   templateUrl: 'templates/book-slot.html',
   controller: 'book-slot-CTRL'  
      }   
    }
})

 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/book');
});
```

side-menu.html

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>

      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
    </button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
</ion-nav-bar>
<ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
     <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Left</h1>
   </ion-header-bar>
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
         List
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

book-slot.html

```
<ion-view view-title="book">
<ion-content> 
book
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: what errors you get?

Comment: I do not get any errors. I outputted a message in my book-slot controller but the app does not get there. However, it does get to the main controller.